# x軸のラベルがdatetimeの日付形式のまま出力されてしまう

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

**概要**
csvデータからmatplotlibを使用し、棒グラフを作成しているのですが
日付形式がdatetimeの型のまま出力されてしまいます。(yyyy-mm-dd hh:ss:mm)
出力されているデータ自体は問題ないのですが、x軸のラベルだけ修正したいと考えてます。(yyyy/mm/ddに変えたい。)

**試してみたこと**
csvデータを読み込んで、、とありますが元データはExcel形式となります。
元データから抽出しているデータはExcel上だと「日付」になっています。
なので
1.対象のカラムをto_datetime()でTimestamp→datetimeに変更。
2.さらにstrftime()を使用しyyyy/mm/dd形式にフォーマット
上記指定してみたのですが、出力されたグラフのx軸はフォーマットされませんでした。

グラフの描画は今回初めて行うので、ご教示いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします

**コード**
<requirements.txt(一部抜粋)>
matplotlib==3.5.3
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
numpy==1.23.2
openpyxl==3.0.10
pandas==1.4.3

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
from encodings import utf_8

TargetPath = "Excelの絶対パス.xlsx"
input_file = pd.ExcelFile(TargetPath)
sheet_names = input_file.sheet_names

#Excel読み込み→csv出力
for i in range(0,len(sheet_names)):
    data = pd.read_excel(TargetPath,sheet_names[i],header=1,index_col=0,usecols=[6,7])
    data.to_csv(sheet_names[i]+'.csv',index=True, encoding = "shift-jis")

#csv読み込み→dataframe作成
df = pd.read_csv('出力したcsvの絶対パス.csv',encoding='shift_jis')

#日付をqueryで抽出したデータをcount()で件数取得する。
df['対応日'] = pd.to_datetime(df['対応日'])
df['対応日'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
df.set_index('対応日', inplace=True)
totaling = df.query('"2020-07-01" <= 対応日 <= "2022-07-31"').resample('M').count()

#Windowsで描画するグラフはデフォだと文字化けするので、フォント指定。
#axisで個別設定して、グラフ描画。
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = "MS Gothic"
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8,5)
ax1 = totaling.plot(kind="bar")
ax1.set_xlabel('集計対象日')
ax1.set_ylabel('件数')
ax1.get_legend().remove()

#グラフ出力
plt.show()
```

Comment: 横軸が時間軸の場合, 大抵は[このようなグラフ](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html)か  [このような](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/timeline.html) 感じになります。(横軸が個別のような) 棒グラフでは無理があるのでは？ (不可能ではないかもしれないが)

Comment: グラフ化するデータを再現するためのデータサンプルを提示いただくことは可能でしょうか？